# Elastic Beanstalk Single Instance SSL .ebextensions config file not working

Tags: node.js, ssl, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was trying to use SSL on my single instance. I think I managed to generate the key and certificate correctly, and after some poking around I managed to locate the instructions for configuring the instance to use it.

So I created an .ebextensions folder in the top level directory and inside I have a file I named singlessl.config

I have included the file below exactly as I have uploaded it. It's not working, does anyone know what the error could be?

(At least something happened though, because now I am getting an "unable to connect" message)

Anyhow I have replaced some strings like the key with other chars but other than that it's exactly the same

The environment is a single instance Node.js with no load balancer and here is the file:

```
Resources:
    sslSecurityGroupIngress: 
        Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
        Properties:
            GroupName: {Ref : awseb-e-10randchar-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-NOW13RANDCHARS}
            IpProtocol: tcp
            ToPort: 443
            FromPort: 443
            CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

files:
    /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf:
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            # HTTPS server

            upstream nodejs {
            server 127.0.0.1:8443;
            keepalive 256;
            }

            server {
                    listen       443;
                    server_name  localhost;

                    ssl                  on;
                    ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
                    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

                    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

                    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
                    ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
                    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

                    location / {
                            proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
                            proxy_set_header   Connection "";
                            proxy_http_version 1.1;
                            proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
                            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    }
            }
    /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
        mode: "000400"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
            Thisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisno
            Thisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisno
            Thisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisno
            Thisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisno
            Thisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisno
            Thisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisno
            Thisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisno
            Thisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisno
            Thisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisno
            Thisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisno
            Thisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisno
            Thisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisno
            Thisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisno
            Thisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisno
            Thisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisno
            Thisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisno
            Thisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisno
            Thisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisno
            Thisisnotmyactualcertificatethisisnotmyactualcertificate
            -----END CERTIFICATE-----

    /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
        mode: "000400"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythis
            Thisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmyactualkeythisisnotmya
            -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I'm not sure what I have wrong. Any insight would be helpful?

Comment: Well I still don't know what I did wrong but I switch to a load balanced version of elastic beanstalk with 1 instance. Easier to configure. Seems to be working so far.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. configuring SSL on a single-instance is harder than setting-up ElasticBeansTalk with loadBalance and defining max instances = 1

For the easy way, steps are in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html

Comment: This may be another way but certainly not the right answer. The drawback will be additional charges for using the load balancer service.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that indentation is extremely important in this file. 
I've just done the configuration in this file and I had a hard time indenting everything correctly. 
Also, keep in mind that when you use a load balancer you spend about $18/month. If you don't mind having this on your budget I'd suggest to go with a load balancer. 
One more thing, if you are using a VPC you need to change the **GroupName** property to **GroupId**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple config file that automates installation of free LetsEncrypt certs on single instance Elastic Beanstalk servers.

http://bluefletch.com/blog/domain-agnostic-letsencrypt-ssl-config-for-elastic-beanstalk-single-instances/

It basically uses container commands to download certbot, get a cert, and configure nginx. The domain name for the cert comes from an env variable, so it can be used without a lot of tweaks from one server to the next.